# Definition of Covering

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having problems understand what is actually meant my the notation $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ I have underlined in green.

[image]

Comment: It's another notation for a function $A:I\to\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, where we write $A_\alpha$ rather than $A(\alpha)$. (Where $\mathcal P(S)$ is the set of subsets of $S$, aka the "power set of $S$.")

Comment: It's a generalization of the idea of a sequence of subsets, $A_1,A_2,\dots$, which is a family with $I=\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just had trouble with decyphering the writing?
Knowing what it is about, I was able to do it:

> Definition 4.9
>
> Let $K$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$, $K\subseteq \mathbb T$.
> A familiy of subsets $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ ($A_\alpha\subseteq \mathbb R$, $I$ is any set) is called a *covering* of $K$ if
> $$K\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha $$

That is: $I$ is any set. For each $\alpha\in I$ we are given a set called $A_\alpha$ and we know that $A_\alpha\subseteq \mathbb R$. As a simple example, $I$ could be $\{1,2,3\}$. Then the familiy consists of three sets $A_1,A_2,A_3$. Note that we do *not* mean the set $\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$ as we do want the members of the family to "know" about their index $\in I$. For example, we might have $A_1=A_3$ and then the *set* $\{\,A_\alpha\mid \alpha\in I\,\}$ would reduce to $\{A_1, A_2\}$.
The main point is however that we are not confined to let $I$ be a finite set, or a subset of $\mathbb N$; we can take *any* set for $I$. For example, we could let $I=\mathbb R$ itself and for $\alpha\in I=\mathbb R$ let $A_\alpha=[\alpha-1,\alpha+42); really, $I$ can be *any* set.

A more formal notation is that we consider a map $I\to\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ and for $\alpha\in I$ we denote the image of $\alpha$ under this map with $A_\alpha$. Speaking of a faimily, however, puts a different focus on this construct (in your mental image, so to speak). Also, we do not have to "artificially" introduce $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$; and in more general settings it may be hard to come up with a set (such as $\mathscr P(\mathbb R)$ in the current example) where all the $A_\alpha$ "live" in the first place.